# UI Kitten functional component - Props undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm developing a react native mobile app using UI Kitten. I'm still fairly new to both react native and UI kitten, so I am using the just the plain Javascript template VS the Typescript template.

I have a functional component screen as shown below. This screen is working just fine. Today I started REDUX implementation.

```
const RequestScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
 // code removed for brevity
}
```

Within this screen I use the useEffect hook to fetch data from my API

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      getServices();
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe;
    };
  }, [navigation]);

  const getServices = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
     // helper function to call API  
    await getAllServices().then((response) => {
      if (response !== undefined) {
        const services = response.service;
        setServices(services);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
    // update redux state
    props.getAllServices(services);
    
  };

 // code removed for brevity

const mapStateToProps = (state) => state;
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getServices: (services) =>
    dispatch({
      type: Types.GET_SERVICES,
      payload: { services },
    }),
});

const connectComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
export default connectComponent(RequestScreen);
```

On this line of code:

```
props.getAllServices(services);
```

I keep getting this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 'props.getAllServices')] at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke

Anytime I try to use "props" in code here. I run into errors. **How do I get the props on this screen?**

I tried changing the screen, as shown below, but that does not work either!

```
const RequestScreen = ({ navigation, props }) => {
  // code removed
}
```

Comment: your issue is related that you are trying to use container pattern that is for class component, for use redux in functional components you should use useSelector and useDispatch from redux.

Comment: I changed the screen component signature to                                                         
               const RequestScreen = ({ navigation, ...props }) => {}  and now I'm getting something in props object, but my props.getAllServices is still throwing an error.

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the props object after changing the screen component as shown below.

```
const RequestScreen = ({ navigation, ...props }) => {}
```